# Разбиение таблицы на страницы при печати

Tags: html, php, css

Всем доброе утро.

Когда я печатаю отчет, который генерируется в таблице, и печатаю, если последняя строка не влезает на первую страницу, то содержание последней строки печатается на два листа. При этом половина букв на одно странице, а другая половина на другой. Как правильно формировать таблицу чтобы не было такого разрва?

[image]

То есть, если на одну страницу не влезает последняя строка целиком, то произходил разрыв страницы и печатался на следующую.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print {
   .pagebreak {
      page-break-after: auto;
   } 
}

<table class="pagebreak">
...
</table>
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось